# C# Picture Box as Accept Button of a Form

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox, acceptbutton

Is there a way to set a picture box as the accept button of a winform? I tried to set it up
on the form properties but it doesn't show up. Thanks for the answers.

Comment: Why? And what do you mean "it doesn't show up"? You have to have the "Accepted Button" control on the form and then use it in the property.

Comment: Unclear at the moment, What are you trying to acheive?

Comment: Property is not named "AcceptPictureBox" it is "AcceptButton"! it has to be a button. More precise `IButtonControl`

Comment: An old hack I've been using for years is to add a button set it as AcceptButton and put it at location -100,-100. User won't know it's there but Enter will work

Comment: I've been trying to set a picture box as the AcceptButton of the form. Trevor Elliot's had already answered my question. Thanks for replies.

Answer (score 5):

No, a `Button` is an `IButtonControl` and a `PictureBox` is not.  The `Form.AcceptButton` property is typed as an `IButtonControl`.

You can override `ProcessCmdKey` on the Form to intercept the Enter key as an alternative:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (keyData == Keys.Enter)
    {
        // call your function instead if you want to do some processing first
        Close();
        return true; // return true to intercept the key press
    }

    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it has to be button to be an "accept button of a winform"
try setting backgroundimage property of a button as desired image and then set it as accept button of form.